# How to group the "closest" numbers in an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of numbers sorted in ascending order. How to group the "closest" numbers (where the difference between the numbers is less than 5, for example)?
So out of [1, 4, 5, 23, 40, 55, 56, 100, 234] I want to get
[[1, 4, 5], 23, 40, [55, 56], 100, 234]

Comment: you need to show some effort into solving the problem, paste your code so far if you have any

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could check the predecessor and if in range add to array.

```js
var data = [1, 4, 5, 23, 40, 55, 56, 100, 234],
    result = data.reduce(function (r, a, i, aa) {
        if (a - aa[i - 1] < 5) {
            if (!Array.isArray(r[r.length - 1])) {
                r[r.length - 1] = [r[r.length - 1]];
            }
            r[r.length - 1].push(a);
            return r;
        }
        r.push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result); // [[1, 4, 5], 23, 40, [55, 56], 100, 234]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method with an empty array as the initial value where update the array by checking the last element.

```js
var data = [1, 4, 5, 23, 40, 55, 56, 100, 234];

var res = data.reduce(function(arr, e) {
  // cache last element index
  var i = arr.length - 1;
  // check array exist atleast one element
  if (i > -1) {
    // check last element is array
    if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
      // compare last element in array and current element is adjacent
      // if yes push into that array otherwise push into main array
      e - arr[i][arr[i].length - 1] < 5 ? arr[i].push(e) : arr.push(e);
      // if last element is not an array
    } else {
      // if last element and current element is adjacent
      // update last element with an array or just push as usual
      e - arr[i] < 5 ? arr[i] = [arr[i], e] : arr.push(e);
    }
    // if array is empty
  } else
  // simply push the element
    arr.push(e);
  // retuen the array reference
  return arr;
  // set initial value as an epty array
}, [])

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

What about another (may shorter)reduce:

```
 newarray=array.reduce((newarray,number)=>{
   var last=newarray.pop()||[];
      if(last.every(elem=>elem+6>number)){
       last.push(number);
       newarray.push(last);
       return newarray;
      }
       newarray.push(last);
       newarray.push([number]);
       return newarray;
      },[]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use reduce and check last element added to add to last array or insert new one, and when you get to last element of data you use `map` to remove arrays with one element.

```js
var data = [1, 4, 5, 23, 40, 55, 56, 100, 234];

var result = data.reduce(function(r, e, i) {
  if (i != 0) {
    (e - data[i - 1] < 5) ? r[r.length - 1].push(e): r.push([e])
  } else {
    r.push([e])
  }
  if (i == data.length - 1) r = r.map(e => e.length == 1 ? e[0] : e)
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question...

Though my answer is slightly convoluted, for experimental purposes you can also do like this...

```js
var data = [1, 4, 5, 23, 40, 55, 56, 100, 234],
  result = data.reduce((p,c) => p.length ? p[p.length-1].length ? c-p[p.length-1][p[p.length-1].length-1] < 5 ? (p[p.length-1].push(c),p)
                                                                                                              : (p.push(c),p)
                                                                : c-p[p.length-1] < 5 ? (p[p.length-1] = [p[p.length-1],c],p)
                                                                                      : (p.push(c),p)
                                         : c-p < 5 ? [[p].concat(c)]
                                                   : [p,c]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

I think it's pretty efficient too.

Ok so let's try something funny... We will feed this algorithm with an array of 1,000,000 random items among 1 ~ 5,000,000 in sorted order and measure how long it takes to group them for a diff < 5.

```js
var data = Array(1000000).fill()
                         .map(_ => ~~(Math.random()*5000000)+1)
                         .sort((a,b) => a-b),
  result = [];
console.time("grouping");
  result = data.reduce((p,c) => p.length ? p[p.length-1].length ? c-p[p.length-1][p[p.length-1].length-1] < 5 ? (p[p.length-1].push(c),p)
                                                                                                              : (p.push(c),p)
                                                                : c-p[p.length-1] < 5 ? (p[p.length-1] = [p[p.length-1],c],p)
                                                                                      : (p.push(c),p)
                                         : c-p < 5 ? [[p].concat(c)]
                                                   : [p,c]);
console.timeEnd("grouping");
console.log(result.length);
```

Like ~200ms in average. Seems cool..!